# k2 item's url under wrong category

Tags: k2, url

Here you are one of my k2 item's url
http://{mysite}/index.php/en/express-news/sport/item/12345

Problem:
All of my k2items are under /sport/ which is wrong

I would like to config it like below:
http://{mysite}/index.php/en/express-news/item/12345
or
http://{mysite}/index.php/en/express-news/{item's own category}/item/12345

What could i do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the most frequent asked questions around Joomla. 
This is happening because of the dynamic nature of the urls.

What you need to do, is to create a K2 categories menu item for each of your K2 categories.

Go in Menus and add your menu items in one of your menus.

If you don't want to display these menu items in a menu in front-end, you could create a "hidden" menu. In this case, create a new menu but don't assign any module for it.
Add in this new menu your menu items for your categories.

This might be of help:
[**Joomla: Creating Menus**](https://docs.joomla.org/Menu)

Comment: had a check of my menus, all of them were set as k2 categories, i just restore them to normal category blog and it temporary solves the problem. thank you anyway